# How to define an original name scope in module/class with Ruby

Tags: ruby

How to define an original name scope in module/class with Ruby

I want to implement class like the following:

```
module SomeModule
  extend OriginalNameScope

  scope(:some) do
    def method1
      puts 1
    end

    def method2
      puts 2
    end
  end
end

class SomeClass
  include SomeModule
end

c = SomeClass.new

# I want to call methods like the following:
c.some_method1
c.some_method2
```

How to implement the OriginalNameScope module?  I found out to get the method definitions in this method, but I don't know how to redefine methods with a prefix scope.

```
module OriginalNameScope
  def scope(name, &method_definition)
    puts method_definition.class
    # => Proc
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually just a combination of some simple standard Ruby metaprogramming patterns and idioms:

```
module OriginalNameScope
  def scope(name)
    singleton_class.prepend(Module.new do
      define_method(:method_added) do |meth|
        if name && !@__recursion_guard__
          @__recursion_guard__ = meth
          method = instance_method(meth)
          undef_method(meth)
          define_method(:"#{name}_#{meth}") do |*args, &block|
            method.bind(self).(*args, &block)
          end
        end
        @__recursion_guard__ = nil
        super(meth)
      end            
    end)
    yield
  end
end
```

I just slapped this together, there's probably a lot that can be improved (e.g. use Refinements) and simplified.